# Google AppScript Lock doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm adding code to a Google Sheet, and have used `LockService.getDocumentLock()` to get a lock.

My problem is that this doesn't seem to work. I can execute the same script multiple times without any issue. Here is the structure of my code:

```
const lock = LockService.getDocumentLock()
global.clickedButton = function() {
  if (lock.tryLock(3000)) {
    Browser.msgBox(`Has Lock? ${lock.hasLock()}`)
    // stuff that takes ~3 minutes
  }
  lock.releaseLock()
}
```

If I keep clicking the button, it runs a new script every time. Each time `hasLock` returns true.

Am I doing something silly, or do Locks just not work?

I've tried:

- Putting the lock creation inside the function
- Using scriptLock, and userLock instead of DocumentLock
- using `lock.waitLock()` instead of `tryLock`. Same issue

Here's a screenshot. I've clicked the button 3 times:

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can I ask you about your question? In your situation, the button is put to the Google Spreadsheet. And, you don't want to run the script continuously by clicking the button during the script is running. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The lock is not actually acquired until the code reaches `tryLock`, so it's normal that the script starts executing every single time you click the button. What's strange is that successive executions actually reach `Browser.msgBox`? They should time out before reaching that, since they'll only wait 3 seconds, while the first execution should take 3 minutes to complete. Can you confirm if they actually reach this line? Or maybe there are relevant parts of the code that you have not shared?